# Failed to obtain DB connection from data source

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, quartz

I'm creating a in memory quartz scheduler in Spring Boot, but getting a connection error.
I have a connected database 'oracle'. once i run I get following error. Can anybody help

```
ERROR [http-nio-80-exec-1] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'myDS': java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
```

this is my quartz.properties file

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon = true

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons = true
#org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount= 20
#org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority= 5

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=25000
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDS

#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources
#============================================================================

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521:fdf
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = username
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = password
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery = select 1
```

this is how I created scheduler in Controller class

```
@RequestMapping("/start")
  public String start() throws SchedulerException {
  Scheduler scheduler;
  SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory  = new StdSchedulerFactory(quartzProperties());
scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
    JobDetail jobDetail =
                JobBuilder.newJob(Job1.class)
                    .usingJobData("job1", "description")
                    .storeDurably(true)
                    .requestRecovery(true)
                    .build();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, Trigger1.fire());
scheduler.start();
return "redirect:/";
}
  @Bean
  public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
  }
```

and Job1.class

```
@Slf4j
public class Job1 implements Job {

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobContext) {
    JobDetail jobDetail = jobContext.getJobDetail();
    log.info(
        "\nname: {}, \nstart: {}, \nnext: {}",
        jobDetail.getJobDataMap().getString("job 1"),
        jobContext.getFireTime(),
        jobContext.getNextFireTime());
  }
}
```

and this is Trigger1 class

```
public class Trigger1 {

  public static Trigger trigger;

  public static Trigger fire() {
    trigger =
        TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("trigger 1")
            .startAt(new Date())
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("/1 * * ? * * *"))
            .build();
    return trigger;
  }
}
```

Furthermore I run this sql scripts in my db [tables_oracle.sql](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/database/tables/tables_oracle.sql)

Comment: firewall? permissions?

Comment: I think I have an error in my code. Dunno where it is

Comment: One of your errors is the fact that you manually start a scheduler. Which will start a scheduler each time you execute the method. Instead you should let Spring start and configure the scheduler using the appropriate classes, that way you can use the Spring Boot configured datasource and inject that into the scheduler.

Comment: The stack trace is incomplete. There must be an ORA error in stack trail in your logs. Please check logs again.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add jdbc maven dependancy.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and creating SchedulerFactoryBean and setting dataSource to it solved the issue